# Bridged networking - VMs ping issue

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kvm, bridge, openvswitch

I'm working with KVM/VirtualBox and OVS. I have two bridges on a host machine, br0 and br1. A VM is connected to br0. The VM is able to ping br0 but it is also able to ping br1, to which it is not connected. Also, I made an iperf server on the VM and a client on the host machine and when I gave the ip of br0 a connection was made and data was transferred but when I gave the ip of br1 a connection was made but no data was able to transfer. All ips are contained in the same subnet. Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: If you're going to down vote can you please explain why you did so?

Comment: What do you mean under "connection was made". Which mode of iperf do you use?

Comment: I used udp and tcp. Let us say that br0 has ip / netmask 192.168.1.10 / 255.255.255.0 and br1 has ip / netmask 192.168.1.20 / 255.255.255.0 and we've connected the VM to br0 when we start iperf on the host machine and the client on the vm it says at the server end that a connection from 192.168.1.10 has been made for both bridges. But for the bridge which has the connection it gives a server report while for the other bridge it says that No ack has been received.

Comment: Last behaviour I can't explain without  network pcap file. Anyway it is very bad practice to use addresses from one IP network in different LANs (which are represented by br0 and br1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can explain on "why br1 address is pingable". This is because in linux when packet is treated as "local-delivery" packet it is received in common point, where source interface is not important. So packet to ANY local interface may be received from any network interface.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this problem? I actually want that my traffic is routed through br0 and then through certain points to get to br1 and not this.

Comment: I guess it is impossible to route traffic to IP that belongs to linux host somewhere outside it. This is matter of classification of IP-traffic - when kernel decides wether packet should be routed or locally delivered. I don't know mechanisms to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: My solution of similar problem was to place target address in another VM. So it is possible to be routed by linux.